Dynamic JSON request payload pass to Rest Adapter in Oracle Integration
I want to pass dynamic request payload JSON. I am using stored procedure with Varchar2 IN and  Varchar2 OUT parameters.
PROCEDURE API(P_REQUEST IN JSON_OBJECT, P_RESPONSE OUT VARCHAR2)

and My request JSON object is like
{
            "function":"GET_S2E_WEIGHT" 
            }

Using this code, I have not received proper request in stored procedure.
So What is best suggested way to implement this ? Stored Procedure IN/OUT parameters and Rest Adapter request parameters ?
Stored Procedure
PROCEDURE API(P_REQUEST IN JSON_OBJECT, P_RESPONSE OUT VARCHAR2)
Request Payload
{ "function":"GET_S2E_WEIGHT"  }
